# How to export with mLab on Heroku

Tags: mongodb, heroku, terminal, mlab

I've been trying this for ages but haven't been able to export my table (collection) from mlab on heroku to a csv file. Below is the export command that they detail on their support page

mongoexport -h ds049180.mlab.com:49180 -d heroku_appXXXXXX -c users -u  -p  -o users.csv --csv -f

I'm executing this command in terminal replacing the "user" in  with my heroku username and doing the same for the password and . Unfortunately, the returned error is "bash -! not recognised" or similar.

Do I need to include quotes for the username and password? I've tried that and it doesn't work, is there something I'm missing?

How can I work this?

Thanks!
Ash

Comment: Hi, you shouldn't be using your heroku username and password. You need to use your database username and password. You can find these in your connection string. The connection string is of the format: `mongodb://username:password@ds012345.mlab.com:12345/dbname`. So you can pull the username and password out of that.

Comment: However, it sounds like the issue you're encountering now is bash not being able to parse your command. If your heroku username and password have special characters in them, that might mess things up. So try with the database username and password and see if it works. If not, can you please share the exact command you used and the exact error, (remembering to block out any confidential info with Xs)?

Comment: Hey @tfogo! Thank you for the help so far. I've got this far now... I enter the following command; "% mongoexport -h dsxxxx.mlab.com:xxxxx -d heroku_appxxxxxxxx -c users -u <username> -p <password> -o users.csv --csv <fieldnames>" however, the terminal returns "find / -name 'mongodb' (wd: /usr/local/lib)" and then stops. I'm not sure what this means...

Comment: Hey, what version of mongoexport are you running (you can run `mongoexport --version` to see)? The `--csv` option was removed in version 3.0.0. So for newer versions you should run something like: `mongoexport -h dsxxxx.mlab.com:xxxxx -d heroku_appxxxxxxxx -c users -u <username> -p <password> -o users.csv --type=csv --fields filed1,field2`.

Comment: Even if the version is a problem, I still wouldn't expect the output you've seen. Just want to double check, you aren't including the % sign at the start as part of the command right? Sometimes people copy the whole thing.

Comment: Hey @tfogo . Thanks so much for this help. So my problem was stupidly including the % sign before the command. Interestingly, now, the result in terminal is "-bash: mongoexport: command not found"

Comment: Great! That just means you don't have mongoexport installed (or it's not in your path). Have you installed MongoDB locally? MongoDB comes with several other tools such as mongoexport. You can download it from here: https://www.mongodb.com/download-center#production

Comment: So mongodb is installed. this is what appears when I search "npm list -g mongoose"... 
/usr/local/lib
`-- mongoose@5.0.13 
Also, it's in the path: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/mongodb/bin:/usr/local/mongodb/bin

Comment: Mongoose is separate from MongoDB. Installing Mongoose won't install MongoDB. It just installs the node driver. What's in `/usr/local/mongodb/bin`?